# What map source/API/tools are recommended to create Web GIS/Mapping application utilising Microsoft technologies?

Tags: geoserver, mapserver, api, software-recommendations, tools

I'm researching about technologies (around Microsoft tech) to create mapping application and would like to have advice/suggestions.

Brief requirement to build mapping application with Microsoft Platform:

1. Adding Pins on the map.
2. Clicking on the pins to get more information as popup.
3. There may be links connecting to various pins (i.e. shortest
   connection, and not actual physical
   representation of path on the map). In some near future there may be
   requirement to represent actual
   physical path between two pins.
4. Clicking on the link to get more information as popup.
5. Base maps can be hosted externally or internally.

Which **base map source can a good candidate** for any apparent reasons? (i.e. Google, Bing or OpenStreetMap).

**Suggestions for API/Controls** for creating web application using **ASP.NET** or **Silverlight** app or windows based **WPF** application.

How **GeoServer or MapServer can be useful** in for such applications?

**Suggestions for other notable tools/API/controls** for designing such applications

Comment: Think there is more than one question in there...

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Google API (and probably Bing API) to provide the dots on a map and the clicking for more information. However it will probably be easier to use OpenLayers, as then you can move from one map provider to another with out having to start again. You may well want to make use of WFS-T to handle adding points to the system, this will allow you to hold the data in your own database.

If you choose to host your basemaps internally then you will need to set up a map server, you can start with GeoServer or MapServer for free or pay out for ArcServer. I'd recommend that you set up the system using Open Standards (WMS, WFS, WFS-T) so that you are not tied to one particular vendor and can move from server to server as your needs dictate.

Answer (score 2):

The [Bing Maps Silverlight control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681884.aspx) would meet all of your requirements above.  One thing worth noting that if you wish to serve your own tiles, you are confined to the Web Mercator spatial reference.  Also, if you plan to render a significant amount of vector data (lines,polygons) with complex symbology, the Silverlight control is limited in its capabilities.

[SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) is another viable option if you are looking to stay within .NET.  It is quite robust, and would allow you to incorporate the major spatial data formats in your application.

Answer (score 1):

I started to play around with some open source technologies to do something very similar.

Viewing side there is http://deepearth.codeplex.com/ which is very similar to the bing silverlight control.

I used postgis as the database and used the .net Entity framework to genereate code that could be used on the ASP.net side to handle the features.

There is also some good work being done http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/ which may help in some part of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Falling into the other tools category - Microsoft are bringing spatial types into their [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723). This is their [object-relational mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), and adding spatial types will allow you to make spatial queries using [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594) without having to worry about the database or SQL e.g.

```
var distances = from s in db.Stores
                select s.Location.Distance(anotherLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

[MapDotNet from ISC](http://www.mapdotnet.com/) is one of Microsofts highest recommended solutions. Silverlight based on lots of room to grow.

Answer (score -2):

For a highly interactive web app, I would recommend using ESRI's Silverlight API for ArcGIS Server.

Comment: [The ArcGIS API for Silverlight is retired](https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/).

Comment: Yes, but not when I posted the comment.

Comment: One important aspect of answers that helps determine their usefulness to our focused Q&A format is their currency.